# Google+ Share as Fanpage

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

I've researched really a lot, but found no way to embed a share button which posts directly on the fanpage, not the personal profile.

I'm working with the JS API and also tried the direct link, neither worked. There is also no way to change account directly in the popup. Settings the `publisherid` also didn't work.

Is there ***any*** way to embed a share button which will share something **on my fanpage**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's nothing you as the website owner can take influence on. It depends on how the user is logged in on Google+.

As a page owner you can create a username/password for the page and login as the page on Google+. Here is a post describing that: https://plus.google.com/108210288375340023376/posts/8nmNsfL8G2R